# Equals method crashes app

Tags: java, android

I am trying to implement the .equals method in Android:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    Product product = (Product) o;
    String prdId = product.getProductId();
    return productId.equals(prdId);
}
```

These lines are skipped when I run a debug and single step through it:

```
Product product = (Product) o;
String prdId = product.getProductId();
```

And the app crashes with no stacktrace. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: if an app crashes "with no stacktrace" it's most likely because you have a catch block somewhere where you don't print or log the stacktrace.
The chance that those lines are not executed is, if you've compiled and built the project, non-existant.

Comment: When you step through `equals()` above, how far does the code actually get?  I don't see a reason for a crash based on what you wrote.

Comment: Before doing equals Check productId and prdId are null or not?

Comment: Hi Tim, the 2 lines are skipped and the line with the return statement is executed and the app crashes.

Comment: are you sure that productId is not null

Comment: might be prdId  have null value so null value with equals method always give exception,

Comment: Hi R2R, productId is not null, I cannot see prdId in debug window because the lines are skipped.

Comment: I think this line is executing  `if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;`

Comment: @ArvindKatte of course that line is executing, but it returns false, otherwise the return productId.equals(prdId); wouldn't execute

Comment: @Egek92 how is that comment even remotely helpful? if it crashes, it returns nothing, meaning that if the information provided in the question is correct, it's not even correct

Comment: @AlanFirblazer I don't see any chance of exception except when this object's productId is null, but you are saying it is not reaching there. Are you sure it is failing inside equals method? Or is it returning false may be because of the method parameter being of some other type?

Comment: I know that this is not much related to the question itself, but why won't you consider Kotlin, especially if you are developing for Android. Kotlin handles situations related with NPE dramatically more adequately

Comment: @GeorgySavatkov one reason might be: who says it's an NPE?

Answer (score 2):

This equals methods can possibly yield a NullPointerException if this.productId is null.

You can use [Objects.equals()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) for a null-safe compare:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    Product product = (Product) o;
    String prdId = product.getProductId();
    return Objects.equals(productId, prdId);
}
```

To be sure, we would really need a StackTrace though...

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your issue related to `NullPointerException`, because productid is `null`, you have to make sure that the productid is not `null` before calling `productid.equals`

```
  @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Product product = (Product) o;
        String prdId = product.getProductId();

        return  (productId == prdId) || (productId != null && 
                 productId.equals(prdId)); // null-safe equals
    }
```

Comment: I do not think that was redundant code, anyway I update the code